# what is the correct way to write a struct to a pipe

Tags: c, linux

On linux, 2.6.x, given the following struct

```
struct A
{
  int a;
  int b;
} ss;
```

The two options that come to my mind for writing the above struct to pipe is

1. memcpy from &ss to sizeof(ss)
2. Copy ss->a, then Copy ss->b

Is one better than the other?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "correct" way but some methods are definitely better than others.

For starters, the size of an int is dependent on the machine, compiler and options.  You probably don't want your network/ipc protocol to vary with those.  Secondly, the order of the bytes in an integer can vary with the same things.  So, first define the size of your integers and the order (endianess).  Let's say you go with 32 bits, big endian.   Then extract these bytes using numeric/logical operations - not byte copying or overlays.  Finally, you might want to actually encode your size assumption in the stream.

Some sample code.  Each function encodes the parameter into the buffer supplied and returns the number of characters used in the buffer.

```
int encode_int(int v, unsigned char *s) {
   s[0] = (v>>24) & 0xff;
   s[1] = (v>>16) & 0xff;
   s[2] = (v>>8) & 0xff;
   s[3] = v & 0xff;
   return 4;
}
int encode_A(struct A *a, unsigned char *s) {
   int offset = 0;
   s[offset++] = 4; // Size of ints - really belongs in a global header or in encode_int
   offset += encode_int(a->a, s+offset);
   offset += encode_int(a->b, s+offset);
   return offset;
}
```

Decoding has to take the supplied bytes and reassemble the integers using logical/arithmetic operations.   Another possibility is to make encode_int use a variable number of bytes (and encode how many it used) if you expect mostly small integers and/or would like to also handle 64bit platforms.   There are many other options - the main thing is don't allow the arbitrariness of the in-memory representation to define your protocol.

Also take a look at ntohl, htonl, ntohs, htons standard functions.

Ps. One final edit - if the size of an integer in the reader is not the same as that in the writer, care has to be taken to correctly handle negative integers.

Comment: NOTE: a pipe is supposed to be local, so there can be no endiannes - issues involved. This might be overkill.

Comment: @wildplasser You could use netcat to pipe stuff over a network, I think.

Comment: Yes of course. Or send it via email. BTW: that would need a *named* pipe. Pipes are only shared by parent<->child processes, which are supposed to live on the same machine.

Comment: You still need to use arithmetic/logic ops to take apart/put together so there will be an endianess to decide.   I'd also be worried it might come back on me if I try to duck these issues.  Easier to do it right at the start.

Comment: The other approach would be to only perform endianness conversion at (possible) border crossings: that would be the point where a "bridge" process is connected to both a (named) pipe and an inet socket. If a process does not (can not) cross the border, it need not do the conversion, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with DrC.

Your simple struct suggest that you are only hinting at your problem at hand.  What you need to think about is the memory layout of your structures, and this can be very different depending upon the CPU, compiler and their the sizeof(int).  Consider:

```
struct B {
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
}
```

The compiler will align 'c' on a sizeof(int) boundary.  That is to say that there will be some padding between 'b' & 'c'.  If sizeof(int) is two then only one extra byte is needed to get 'c' to start on an int boundary.  If sizeof(int) is four, as it is on most 32-bit processors, then three padding bytes are needed.  The problem really comes with 64-bit processors.  sizeof(int) can be four or eight.

So the simplistic answer to your question is transmit each element of the struct separately as this avoids transmitting any padding bytes.  But you'll only get away with this if both ends of your pipe agree on both what sizeof(<data-type>) equates to, AND the byte ordering of ints, longs, long longs, float, doubles, ...

But given the network bandwidth these days I think it is best to use an ASCII based transmission protocol (such as XML) unless there is a very good reason not too.

Comment: " But you'll only get away with this if both ends of your pipe agree on both what sizeof(<data-type>) equates to, AND the byte ordering of ints, longs, long longs, float, doubles, ..." That *agreement* is called a *protocol*. Expectations for element order and size are the very definition of this. In this case I concur that DrC is a bit overkill, since it is a pipe and the therefore local on the machine, especially if you own the code on both ends. But  beyond that, he is spot-on in general portability. I do find interest that you think his answer is overkill, but an XML schema is somehow not.